# What is character 0x1f?

Tags: android, xml

I've just imported a chunk of text into a string element for a book app and I'm getting this error : An invalid XML character (Unicode:0x1f) was found in the element content of this document.
I looked it up here http://lwp.interglacial.com/appf_01.htm and the description says US (removing underlining doesnt seem to work). 
What is this character so I can remove it if possible.
I'm very new to android so simple answers please :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

US means "Unit separator". This is an invisible character, so you should open your text file with some text editor that can show the invisible characters and remove them. I think that probably Notepad++ will give you this functionality:

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Downloaded notepad++, opened file and it showed up straight away, brilliant! Thank you :)

Answer (score 26):

0x1f is a [Unit Separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_separator), an archaic way to separate fields in a text (Like `,` or `Tab` in CSV).

It is indeed [not a valid text character](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets) in XML 1.0 (but [allowed in XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets)). In a UTF-8 input string, you can also safely replace the byte `0x1f` with `0x09`(Tab) to work around the problem. Alternatively, declare the document as XML 1.1 and use an XML 1.1 parser.

Comment: Thanks Phihag, but my eclipse says otherwise. I'm using xml version 1.0, which seems to be standard for android projects on eclipse. Should I be updating it?

Comment: @Broo Unlikely that updating will help, but maybe file a bug if that problem persists. I misunderstood your question. Next time, if it is not programming-related (i.e. you want to *do* something instead of *writing code* that does something), please ask on http://superuser.com/

Comment: WRONG: 0x1f is not a legal XML character in XML 1.0. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets. It can be expressed as `#x1f;` in XML 1.1, but not in XML 1.0. Downvoting.

Comment: Thanks @phihag. I faced similar issue of tab in my build, I replaced it with spaces to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nodepad++ you will find the "Unit separator".

Like the picture:

[image]