# Unable to create record in MS-Dynamic CRM from mulesoft

Tags: java, web-services, mule, dynamics-crm, dataweave

Following is what I am doing.

- I am using mule MS-Dynamics connector to create a contact
- I get records from mysql Database (Inserted from source file)
- Transform it to CRM specific object in dataweave

This works for over **10 Million** records. But for a few hundred records
I am getting the following error:

> Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: Invalid white space character (0x1f) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity)

With some research I found out that  (0x1f) represents US "Unit separator".

I tried replacing this character in my dataweave like this

```
%var replaceSaaj = (x) -> (x replace /\"0x1f"/ with "" default "")
```

but the issue persists.
I even tried to look for these characters in my source file and database with no luck.
I am aware that this connector internally uses SOAP services.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693153/what-is-character-0x1f I followed this to backtrack these characters in source file...but no luck